# NEED EXCEL IN COUNTIF AND COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

ı am stuck in formula and ı don't know how to solve this problem.
ı want a write a formula which is check the names if the names are same counts data which is in the other column.
Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem ı use SUM(COUNTIFS( method.

example = sum(countifs(B:B;name which ı described for criteria;E:E;{"and this part ı described all data names which is in E column";"like this";"as far as want"}))

ı tried to explain with best way ı hope this answer will help you.
maybe there is a short way to do this if you solve this with other way please tell us.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula below the name is in A2. The formula searches all the column B for duplicates and writes the number of matches found in its own cell. Therefore the formula must be in a column other than A or B.

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)
```

Say, you have the formula in cell C2, you can copy it down as far as column A has values and do the count for every one of the names in column A.

Comment: That isn't the way things work here. Please publish the solution you employed. As a guide to others mark it as "Selected" even if it's your own solution.